# Escape within Blade

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-blade

How can I escape something in Blade templating within PHP for CSS.

Let me explain:
I have several divs (12 boxes) and I want this div to have a background. Its loaded with an foreach so every box will have its own background (and some more info).

When I try:

```
<div class="box" style="background-image: url('http://localhost:8080/Artist%20Agency/artistlaravel/{{$cat[0][\"picture\"]}}');">
```

The following error:
syntax error, unexpected `T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting T_STRING`

When I do:

```
<div class="box" style="background-image: url('http://localhost:8080/Artist%20Agency/artistlaravel/{{$cat[0]['picture']}}');">
```

No Error at all, it just doesn't work. The url that gets generated is:
`http://localhost:8080/Artist%20Agency/artistlaravel/uploads\CATEGORY_ZangersPsakKDURhFlo.jpg`

And appearantly that doesn't work either. When I copy this link to my browser it works. But in the code it doesn't work. When I do the following, it works. But that is not dynamic...

```
 <div class="box" style="background-image: url('http://localhost:8080/Artist%20Agency/artistlaravel/uploads/CATEGORY_ZangersPsakKDURhFlo.jpg');">
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a big difference in blade between

```
{{ $value }}
```

and

```
{{{ $value }}}
```

The latter escapes, the former doesn't

Comment: And I did search for this for like a million years. I love you. Thank you.